# keep class diagram and code synchronized

Tags: architecture, uml, class-diagram

I am trying to design my applications know before writing some code. I've created class diagram of all classes am going to use and then generated code from them using [Astah](http://astah.net/).

The problem occurs when I want to change a method of some class or add a new one. I should do this twice: once in the class diagram and once in the source code. Several evolutions of this kind being proceeded, my class diagram becomes easily out of date.

Is there some approach to avoid this? Can I update already existing code from activity diagram?

Thank you in advance

Comment: "_I am too lazy_" is not very motivating for other people to help. Why d'you thing someone would/should help _lazy_ guy? Hint: search for "reverse engineering" in `[uml]` tagged older questions filtered by the programming language you use

Comment: Actually this a very bad practice in programming to do the same thing two times, so I hope people would understand. Nevertheless, thank you for your hint. I'll check that.

Comment: I did not question code reuse in programming. I questioned your own shown research effort (as in http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Optimize and value your resources (life, time) but don't be lazy and don't ask other people to do your work. Without specifying the language and showing some pieces of the code and diagrams you're talking about, this question is too broad and too abstract. See also http://agilemodeling.com/essays/bestPractices.htm

Answer (score 0):

For answering your question, it seems to me pertinent to consider the way UML is used.

In [UML distilled](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/772683422), Martin Fowler considers three ways of using UML:

1. Sketch
2. Blueprint
3. Executable UML

**1. Sketch**

The sketch use of UML is convenient for [refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) programs, a practice Fowler is [seriously interested in](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/863697997). In general this is appropriate to have a synthetic perception of an existing program.

**2. Blueprint**

Blueprint is in a way the academic use of the language. The main problem is in software evolution: the models have to be revisited with the code not to become legacy.

**3. Executable UML**

Executable UML is a kind of extreme practice of the language in which it becomes the main way of expression for a program. In that context, the program is usually generated from the initial UML model which contains all the software informations. The source code is only a transition form of the software. The software evolves with the model, code generated again. This is possible only with a complete UML modeling of the software. In a few words, this is a radical use of UML.

I think the distinction between these three ways of using UML is a pertinent consideration about the general use of UML.

**UML as an interface for source code modification**

However I understand what you are looking for: there should be another (fourth) way of using UML, as an interface for source code modification. A few solutions exist but none is really convenient, here are the initiatives I identified :

- [Green UML](http://green.sourceforge.net/) is an Eclipse plug-in by the University of Buffalo which uses its own class diagram editor
- [Code Canvas](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/codecanvas/) was a research project by Microsoft, not UML but interesting, an article is available in [the ACM communications](http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2010/8/96613-software-development-with-code-maps/fulltext)
- [BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org/) is a very light IDE including a class diagram editor modifying the source code
- [*Coffea* UML](http://bdulac.github.io/coffea/) is a personal project

A few words here about [*Coffea*](http://bdulac.github.io/coffea/). Its purpose was to link the [Eclipse JDT](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/) refactoring functions to the [Eclipse UML2Tools](http://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT-UML2Tools) diagram editors. It worked correctly with the class diagram editor. My ambition was to extend it to the activity diagram. Unfortunately the UML2Tools have become legacy since then. *Coffea* is not dead but almost. I have separated the core UML2 functions from the UML2Tools editors. My intentions are detailed in the project site. However I work on it on my spare time and I have other occupations.

UML can be used as an interface for source code modification if and only if the modification is only on one aspect (e.g. behavioral or structural). It would be quite impossible to have a comprehensive edition of the software outside of the scope of Executable UML. The supposed editor for such a purpose would be a combination of multiple diagrams, what would be very complicated. Such an editor should be close to the sketch mode described by Fowler.

**Conclusion**

Unfortunately, I think that UML as an interface for source code modification is currently something theoretic. A main challenge would be to integrate the modification with an initial UML model (your case). Given the variety of UML tools, I think Fowler's uses of UML are the only serious solutions. It seems you can only use [Astah](http://astah.net/) for Executable UML. I am not even sure the tool provides all the features to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, may be I need to change my approach then.

Comment: This is up to you, the relationship between UML and code is not obvious. In my opinion, the UML tooling should be more oriented toward a sketch use more suitable for day after day development. Few organizations accept the blueprint mode and very few fanatics take care of executable UML. A consequence is a poor use of UML in enterprise development. Please let me know how you will manage your modeling...

Answer (score -1):

Delphi Architect (by Embarcadero) is suitable, assuming you are familiar with Object Pascal. I used it extensively around 2005-2010. In 2022, it is still available.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).