# How to bind UML with code?

Tags: oop, database-design, uml

I am beginning in UML and software analyse and i do not understand how  UML and  diagrams can influence  coding and  software architecture  while we can directly build the code and its data base without diagrams.
I read lot of tutorials abouat the subject but not enough to understand the utility of UML in coding.
I understand everey diagram and its role. That is not my problem but i do not yet understand their roles after the analyse and design phase.
So what is the role of UML in coding phase of a software ?
Thank you.

Comment: Easy-to-use documentation simplifying future maintenance

Answer (score 1):

The comment by @xmojmr already puts it right. UML creates a model (hence the M in UML) of a system. A model reduces information of a system to a level so it is a) manageable and b) complete. Human brains are not computers and you need a means of communication what the system is all about. You can do that as pure code, as paper document and as UML model. A combination of all is not uncommon. As long as you have tiny systems you can live with pur code and tools like Doxygen. But once it starts getting complex you need some handles. UML offers these to end users, architects, testers, developers, managers, etc. Along with UML you will also need a methodology. UML delivers the syntax how to document a system. But you need some structure above to write a nice novel.

Answer (score 0):

UML-based models play an essential role for coding/implementing a software system in ***model-based*** (or *model-driven*) ***development***. The basic idea is that you start making a model of your problem domain (the ***domain model***), then you derive from it a platform-independent ***design model***, which can be transformed into platform-specific ***implementation models*** (e.g. for Java- or C#-based platforms) that are finally encoded in the target languages.

The most prominent part of model-based development is the encoding of model classes (forming the model layer in an MVC architecture for apps) based on a data model (a UML class model) that has been derived from an information design model, which was obtained from a domain information model (where all these information/data models are UML class models).

You can find an instructive example of model-based development in my tutorial book [Engineering Front-End Web Apps with Plain JavaScript](http://web-engineering.info/JsFrontendApp-Book).

Answer (score 0):

This one is in my point of view a duplicate of [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27869353/1207019). It can't be flagged because there is no accepted answer. The [related question on meta stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224224) does not provide a clear solution to that situation.

I think my [personal answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27878818/1207019) was relevant and is applicable to the current question.

To be synthetic, [Martin Fowler considers current uses of UML](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UmlMode.html). I think he describe the current practices. Perhaps should these evolve ?

Perhaps would the initial question be the right place to discuss ?